# Why does calling one `setState` function update an entirely separate state value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue where one `setState` function is updating two separate state values.

I am trying to make a small React sortable array. The program should behave like so:

- fetches data on mount
- stores that data in both `unsortedData` & `displayedData` state hooks
- when a user clicks "toggle sorting" button the array in `displayedData` is sorted (using `.sort()`)
- on a second click of "toggle sorting" it should set `displayedData` to be the same value as `unsortedData` - restoring the original order

However, on first click of toggle sorting, it sorts both `unsortedData` & `displayedData`, which means I lose the original data order. I understand I could store their order, but I'm wanting to know why these state values appear to be coupled.

[Stackblitz working code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-baizu7).
[GIF showing issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yoc6q.gif)

I cannot find where this is happening. I can't see any object/array referencing going on (I'm spreading for new objects/arrays).

Code here:

```
const Test = () => {
  const [unsortedData, setUnsortedData] = useState([])
  const [displayedData, setDisplayedData] = useState([])
  const [isSorted, setisSorted] = useState(false)

  const handleSorting = () => setisSorted(!isSorted)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSorted === true) setDisplayedData([...unsortedData.sort()]) // sort data
    if (isSorted === false) setDisplayedData([...unsortedData]) // restore original data order
  }, [isSorted, unsortedData])

  useEffect(() => {
    const mockData = [3, 9, 6]
    setUnsortedData([...mockData]) // store original data order in "unsortedData"
    setDisplayedData([...mockData])
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {displayedData.map(item => item)}
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => handleSorting()}>Toggle sorting</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hint: your click triggers `handleSorting`, which changes the one state value, which triggers a rerender, which runs your `useEffect` calls, which in turn do something that answers your question.

Comment: Hi @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans! Thanks for helping! I understand the flow of events, but in the last event, the useEffect, I'm not running `setUnsortedData`, yeh it's value is being updated... no idea why!

Comment: No, but you're running `unsortedData.sort()`, so you're [modifying that array](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) (just not through its associated state update function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.sort` function mutates the array, so when you do this:

```
setDisplayedData([...unsortedData.sort()])
```

You are mutating unsortedData, then making a copy of it afterwards. Since you mutated the original array, that change can display on the screen when the component rerenders.

So a minimum fix would be to copy first, and sort afterwards:

```
setDisplayedData([...unsortedData].sort())
```

> Also, why do I need the useEffect? Why can't I just move the contents of the useEffect (that has the if statements in) into the handleSorting function?

Moving it into handleSorting should be possible, but actually i'd like to propose another option: have only two states, the unsorted data, and the boolean of whether to sort it. The displayed data is then a calculated value based on those two.

```
const [unsortedData, setUnsortedData] = useState([3, 9, 6]) // initialize with mock data
const [isSorted, setisSorted] = useState(false)

const displayedData = useMemo(() => {
  if (isSorted) {
    return [...unsortedData].sort();
  } else {
    return unsortedData
  }
}, [unsortedData, isSorted]);

const handleSorting = () => setisSorted(!isSorted)

// No use useEffect to sort the data
// Also no useEffect for the mock data, since i did that when initializing the state
```

The benefits of this approach are that

1. You don't need to do a double render. The original version sets isSorted, renders, then sets displayed data, and renders again
2. It's impossible to have mismatched states. For example, in between that first and second render, isSorted is true, and yet the displayed data isn't actually sorted yet. But even without the double render case, having multiple states requires you to be vigilant that every time you update unsortedData or isSorted, you also remember to update displayedData. That just happens automatically if it's a calculated value instead of an independent state.

Comment: That is so helpful! Thanks so much! So it was some annoying object reference mutation stuff! 

Ah yeh, I like that approach! Less state changes = less re-rendering, very good point! 

Thanks mate, really appreciate it! 

Comment: Trying to do it all in one function doesn't seem to work:
```
const handleSorting = () => {
    setisSorted(!isSorted)
    if (isSorted === true) setDisplayedData([...unsortedData].sort()) // sort data
    if (isSorted === false) setDisplayedData([...unsortedData]) // restore original data order
  }
```
the first click of toggle does nothing, the next click does work. The rendered ui seems to be one render behind what I want... when isSorted is false it is sorted, and vice verca.
[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-baizu7?file=src/App.js)

Comment: Is this because I should be doing it in a useEffect way ("Listen" to state changes in dep array and run these functions based on those changes)? 
It would be much more concise if I could do it in one function.

Comment: `Trying to do it all in one function doesn't seem to work` The reason that code is always one step behind is that you have your if statements backwards. `isSorted` contains the *old* value, not the new value. So if `isSorted` is true, then you want to *unsort* the array, but you're sorting it instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help @nicholas-tower! I really appreciate it! Oh right... but I'm updating the state value before the if statements. Why is it that the state change is not effecting the component before the if statements? 

If you have recommended reading on this type of react rendering I'd love to hear it! 

Comment: `isSorted` is a local `const`. It will never change, and that's not what `setIsSorted` does. When you call `setIsSorted`, you tell react to render the component again. When that new render eventually happens, a new local const will be created with the new value, but the code from the old render has no access to this new render.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display sorted array to user only when the user presses the button, you could use this code statement (orignaly coppied from [vue3 todo list](https://v3.vuejs.org/examples/todomvc.html))

```js
const filters = {
  none: (data) => [...data],
  sorted: (data) => [...data].sort((a, b) => a - b),
}

const Test = () => {
  const [unsortedData, setUnsortedData] = useState([])
  const [currentFilter, setCurrentFilter] = useState('none')

  useEffect(() => {
    const mockData = [3, 9, 6]
    setUnsortedData([...mockData])
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
         {/* All magic is going here! */}
         {filters[currentFilter](unsortedData).map(item => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)}
      </ul>
      <br />
      <button
        onClick={() =>
            setCurrentFilter(currentFilter === 'none' ? 'sorted' : 'none')}>
          Toggle sorting
       </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```